# CKEditor correctly inserting images only in Editor, But not displaying images on Web Page after submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, ckeditor

CKEditor correctly inserting images only in Editor, But not displaying images on Web Page after submit.
for example I have image for paypal in CKEditor. But after submit it shows this:

"http://example.com/%22https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif/%22

Answer (score 0):

This will happen when the link is relative to the CMS i.e `../Image/MyImage.jpg` but when it goes on the front end of the website, it can't find the file.

If you have your Image mapped like `/Image/MyImage.jpg` (notice the removal of `..`) it will navigate from the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

simply on the front end in the console looks for errors and try to see the path of images errors and figure it out that  what is the path with which u  are saving the image and what is is the pata from which on the fronnt end your web browser is looking for image path.